# How can i move a secondary level Tab to the parent Tabs

Tags: routes

I use the Profile2 module and i get in the user edit view the secondary tabs with the extra profile information. How can i move it to the parent tabs and hide the child tabs: "Edit | Info".

Comment: Could tab tamer help? https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer

Comment: Maybe, but i don`t want for only one tab install an extra module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for each page, the type of tab is decided my a parameter 'type'. So you can do a hook_menu_alter() on the specific page to change that. Please have a look at the "Rendering Menu Items As Tabs" section of the documentation for [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to gain idea of what options do what.

Comment: I can only hide the tab, but other things doesn`t work. The tab is evertime hidden, also when i try to rename the title from the tab with these little function. function newtemplate_menu_alter(&$items) {$items['user/%user/edit/extra'] = array('title'=> 'info',)}

Comment: Bruno, the stuff you wrote in your function will render the menu useless because you are overriding the entire menu definition with that array array('title'=> 'info');
So in effect your menu definition, if it was:
$items['user/%user/edit/extra'] = array('page_callback' => '',
                                      'access_callback' => '',)

becomes just this:
$items['user/%user/edit/extra'] = array('title'=> 'info');
I think you need to grab another level in the array and do something like this:
$items['user/%user/edit/extra']['type'] = MENU_LOCAL_TASK;

This will only change the type param

Comment: ok, i understand. it`s not so good to overwrite the array, but then should this work $items['user/%user/edit/extra']['title'] = 'info'; ... it doesn`t work, the tab is still not showing with the renamed title.